# Why does using c++ Input class when I am trying to simulate mouse move in game leads to filck-move into ground ( in game ofc )?

Tags: c++, input, bots, mouse

I wanted to make "bot" that would play simple 3D games. I ve started with minecraft. No matter how much value of x or y is incremented/decremented it causes terrible flick move with eventually spining when i used loops )into ground and nothing more ( i tried to delete flag MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE  ) . I know that game centers cursor in the middle of screen and then reads the difference when its moving and centers cursor again. I want to know what is wrong with that method or how to do it properly, thanks.

```
int main(){
    Sleep(3000);

    POINT point = showCoords();
    MouseMove(point.x + 0.1, point.y);
    Sleep(20);                                                                                      
    }

POINT getCords() {

    POINT point;

    if (GetCursorPos(&point))
        std::cout << point.x << "," << point.y << "\n";

    return point;                                                                                       
}

void MouseMove(int x, int y){
    double fScreenWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 1;
    double fScreenHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - 1;
    double fx = x * (65535.0f / fScreenWidth);
    double fy = y * (65535.0f / fScreenHeight);
    INPUT Input = { 0 };
    Input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    Input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
    Input.mi.dx = fx;
    Input.mi.dy = fy;
    ::SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));                                                          
}
```

Comment: *"I know that game centers cursor in the middle of screen and then reads the difference when its moving and centers cursor again"* maybe this assumption is wrong. Can you prove this?

Comment: I am 100% sure that what  3D games do is setting cursor in the middle of screen. What is more i was testing it with method GetCursorPos what confirmed that. I am not sure about how game calcualte it into real movement of camera but it seems to be like I wrote.

Comment: I think dropping the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag and sending _relative_ movements is the way to go.

Comment: I tried it ( if it means that i have to just delete | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE part ) but the result was that despite of the filick in game i also get the cursor in the right bottom screen corner. Can you tell me if i did the thing you that are talking about ?